# MS Access Tables with MSFlexgrid

Tags: ms-access, vb6, msflexgrid

How can one display two tables in a single MSFlexgrid control in VB6?

Answer (score 0):

You can add anything to the flexgrid.

The only thing that you have to do is

```
flexGrid.AddItem ""
```

This adds a new row to the FlexGrid. Now you have to add the information to each cell. For each cell, set

```
flexGrid.Row = row
flexGrid.Col = col
```

and then add the information to the cell with:

```
flexGrid.Text = info
```

So, you have to iterate through your tables and add your data to the flexGrid.